# Проблема с алгоритмом Морзе

Tags: java, алгоритм, перевод

Написал простенький транслятор Морзе, но столкнулся с ошибочной расшифровкой\шифровкой. Не понимаю, где ошибся.

```
  private Map<String, String> reverseMap = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String, String> baseMap = new HashMap<>();
    private boolean isMorze = false;

    public void checkLanguage(String str) {

        boolean isLatinAlphabet = str.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");

        if (isLatinAlphabet) {
            translate(str);
            isMorze = false;
        } else {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : baseMap.entrySet()) {
                reverseMap.put(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
            }
            isMorze = true;
            translate(str);
        }

    }

    public void translate(String start) {
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
        String result = "";
        if (!isMorze) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : baseMap.entrySet()) {
                if (start.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                    temp.append(entry.getValue());
                }
            }
        }

        if (isMorze) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : reverseMap.entrySet()) {
                if (start.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                    temp.append(entry.getValue());
                }
            }
        }

        result = temp.toString();
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Yours string: " + start);
        System.out.println("In Morze it's look's like: ");
        System.out.print(result + "\n");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------");
        result = "";

    }

    public void init() {
        baseMap.put("a", ".-");
        baseMap.put("b", "-...");
        baseMap.put("c", "-.-.");
        baseMap.put("d", "-..");
        baseMap.put("e", ".");
        baseMap.put("f", "..-.");
        baseMap.put("g", "--.");
        baseMap.put("h", "....");
        baseMap.put("i", "..");
        baseMap.put("j", ".---");
        baseMap.put("k", "-.-");
        baseMap.put("l", ".-..");
        baseMap.put("m", "--");
        baseMap.put("n", "-.");
        baseMap.put("o", "---");
        baseMap.put("p", ".--.");
        baseMap.put("q", "--.-");
        baseMap.put("r", ".-.");
        baseMap.put("s", "...");
        baseMap.put("t", "-");
        baseMap.put("u", "..-");
        baseMap.put("v", "...-");
        baseMap.put("w", ".--");
        baseMap.put("x", "-..-");
        baseMap.put("y", "-.--");
        baseMap.put("z", "--..");
        baseMap.put("1", ".----");
        baseMap.put("2", "..---");
        baseMap.put("3", "...--");
        baseMap.put("4", "....-");
        baseMap.put("5", ".....");
        baseMap.put("6", "-....");
        baseMap.put("7", "--...");
        baseMap.put("8", "---..");
        baseMap.put("9", "----.");
        baseMap.put("0", "-----");
        baseMap.put(" ", " ");
    }
```

На выходе имею следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD: скинув код сюда, заметил, что он все подходящие буквы добавляет в строку.

Comment: `start.contains` - этим вы нарушаете весь порядок. Замените хотя бы на проверку `startwith`. И удаляете то что добавили... В общем тут много проблем. И вообще как различить `am` и `j` у них будет одинаковый код `.---` точно таблица правильная? Или пробелы к примеру расставить надо?

Comment: @pavel подскажите признак, по которому можно определить конкретную букву, ведь скажем есть буква "e", а есть буква "f" и получается, что "е" = "." а "f" = "..-.", это и сбивает с толку. Как по длине можно понять, какая это именно буква?

Comment: Между буквами должны быть разделители (паузы), иначе никак.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%B5):

> За единицу времени принимается длительность одной точки. Длительность тире равна трём точкам. Пауза между элементами одного знака — одна точка, между знаками в слове — 3 точки, между словами — 7 точек

Т.е. вы не учли, что часть символов в морзе-представлении может содержать другие символы. Вам надо также как и было задумано добавлять разделители меж буквами и словами. Так у вас не будет проблем с расчленением рядов до отдельные символы.

Также вам надо искать совпадения с ключами методом `equals()`, а не `contains()`. Так вы избежите неверных совпадений

Comment: я пробовал делать через `equals()` - в этом случае он совпадений не находит вовсе.